# How to calculate shipping cost based on Zip Codes

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping, shipping-methods

the scenario is this:
The site offers two types of shipping, one standard and one fast and the customer can choose what he wants.

The request is to apply a surcharge fixed for certain zip codes to both expeditions.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice free extension that does that: [MatrixRate](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webshopapps-matrixrate-1-multiple-table-rates-extension.html).

It works by importing a CSV file with zip codes, countries, weight and price. You can use a wildcard ("*") if you don't care about a certain column. It works at website scope.